# Cleaning data to create consistent variable naming

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am using a "messy" set of data where there was no control on variable input during the data entry process.  I need to have uniformity in my categories in order to proceed with my analysis, and I dread having to manually clean the data. An example set looks like this:

```
Name<-c("Goat","goat","BillyGoat"," Billy Goat", "Billy.Goat","Bilygoat","Billy-Goat", 'Goat', "Billy/Goat","Billy*Goat",
        "Dog","DOG","Dogs"," Dogs", "  Dogs","Dogs  ", "DVD","D.V.D",
        "XYZ","XZY","Champlain","Chaplain","LakeChamplain","Lake Champlain")

Number<-seq(1,24)

DF<-data.frame(Name,Number)
```

I have capitalization issues, extra spaces added, inconsistent use of special characters (periods, hyphens, etc), and some obvious spelling issues.

It's pretty easy to take care of the first two issues by making everything lower case and removing all spaces:

```
DF$Name<-tolower(DF$Name)
DF$Name<-gsub(" ","",DF$Name)
```

But given my actual dataset is pretty massive, I'd like to avoid manually cleaning up spelling and other issues with my data. Given this is a common problem in data science, are there any R resources I can use to clean up this kind of messy data?

Comment: For the spelling, you'll probably need some sort of dictionary to compare words against—that's probably a secondary task. How do you want to go about handling other things: all lowercase, no spaces, no punctuation? Or some other set of rules?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clean_names()` from `janitor` package.

```
DF <- DF %>% clean_names()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I use the above code as is, I don't see any change in DF, other than the colnames change to lower case